# Google sheets - Padding dates in a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know if there's a way to pad empty dates rows when doing a pivot table when there're not present in the source table.

More context about what I'm trying to do. I track workout data and its duration. I have different activities. I want to make an aggregate weekly summary visualized with a stacked bar chart.

```
date        week        activity        duration (min)  duration (hours)
26/05/2023  22/05/2023  strengthening   60              1:00:00
28/05/2023  22/05/2023  climbing        90              1:30:00
29/05/2023  29/05/2023  strengthening   13              0:13:00
30/05/2023  29/05/2023  climbing        120             2:00:00
```

After every workout, I add the date, the duration and the activity. The first day of the week and the duration in hours in calculated.

I then do a pivot table.
[image]

Then plot it.

[image]

In this case, there is no data between the 17/07/2023 and 31/07/023 and this week doesn't appear in the graph. I would like the week date to appear, with a zero value.